# Which type of screen will provide good video quality for PSX/PS2?

Tags: monitor, ps2, ps1

I tried to become accustomed to very blurred and ugly graphics on PSX/PS2 plugged into my TV with a big screen, but it depriving me of any enjoyment of playing games.
So I'm wondering which type of TV or monitor special dedicated for this old Sony's consoles. Generally, the most interesting option for me is an LCD monitor/TV with about 20 inches diagonal screen, but I am not sure if an LCD monitor/TV will behave differently than a big TV OLED, which kills all the fun in the game.
Does it make sense to prepare a gaming station with the LCD monitor, or am I convicted of old, heavy, and ugly CRT TV?

If some of you will confirm, that LCD variants can handle video playback in acceptable quality, the next question is about preferred inputs available in devices. Most of the LCD monitors with mentioned dimensions have just VGA and DVI inputs, so I am a little afraid about quality loss due to converters from VGA to SCART/RCA. However, this problem with converters does not exist in the case of the LCD TV or LCD-TV-monitor hybrids, because as I can imagine, they have these inputs.

Comment: Hey there. This question in its current state reads as a recommendation/shopping question, which is unfortunately off topic for our site. If you'd like though, please edit the question to take the recommendation part out. If the question reads more like "which type of monitor works best for the PS1/2", you should be well within the bounds of our rules. I'm interested in this question as well, so if you need help, I'm happy to edit.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic even in its current state. The question doesn't ask which TV to buy, but what _kind_ of screen would allow for a good play experience.

Comment: As @AJPerez said, I did not ask about a specific model of the screen, but rather about technology/type of that. Rather, what I had in mind was which type of screen would provide a pretty enjoyable gameplay experience with few drawbacks. For example, I realize that a CRT TV will work well with PSX/PS2, but you also have to keep in mind that such equipment takes up a lot of space, unlike a flat LCD screen. The question is whether it will technically work well enough with these old consoles.

Comment: You may not have intended to ask it in such a way, but looking at the bounds of our Recommendations rule, it reads that way. Specifically, "does it make sense to buy..." is why people are voting to close as a shopping recommendation. You'll want to edit this question, or it will be closed.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf thanks for the complete explanation. I have made a few changes that I hope make the question more compatible with the rules. You said before that you are also interested in this question, so If from your perspective I didn't quite get it right, please feel free to provide some changes if it's still against the rules.

Comment: If it's retro for the sake of being retro, then you need a CRT to play Duck Hunt. Otherwise it's time to look at emulators, because at 640×480i a PS1 *will* look like crap on anything with a higher native resolution. A moderately robust CPU can play PS1s at 4k.. for PS2s you might need a gaming rig to get 4k at an acceptable fps. - **A 4k TV and a CPU that can push 4k**; that's how you make *any 6th gen game or less (minus the 360) ever* look good.